# Adding snippet and injecting it on product page in shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm developing a Shopify app.
On app installation, I want to create a snippet and upload some assets like images and JS.
That snippet should be injected in the product.liquid file.

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with your code, or a specific part of the process you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for creating assets using API

https://docs.shopify.com/api/asset

While passing the key parameter you can pass whether it is going to be a snippet or asset.

{ "key" : "**assets**/bg-body-green.gif" }